# OpenCV with Visual Studio 2013(C++): findContours breakpoint error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am using OpenCV version 2.4.10.

When I debug I get the breakpoint error: wkernelbase.pdb not loaded.

Furthermore, I get this error in the output of Visual Studio:

```
First-chance exception at 0x7543C42D in Perspective.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x003FEDDC.
Unhandled exception at 0x7543C42D in Perspective.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x003FEDDC.
```

In my application, the command line prints this out:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed <0 <= contourIdx< <int>last> in cv::drawContours, file...\..\..\..\opencv\imgproc\src\contours.cpp, line 1810
```

Any suggestions as to how to deal with this? Here is my code:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "iostream"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Mat image;
    image = imread("shape.jpg", 1);
    namedWindow("Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Display window", image);
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    Canny(gray, gray, 100, 200, 3);

    /// Find contours   
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    RNG rng(12345);
    findContours(gray, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
    /// Draw contours
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(gray.size(), CV_8UC3);
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
        drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
    }

    imshow("Result window", drawing);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I know my image is in the correct directory as well.

Comment: please have another look at the opencv libs you're linking. do not mix debug and release libs, or use release libs with a debug build, or the other way.

Comment: Hi berak, thanks for the fast response. I checked them just now and I have used the right libs (i am currently running it through debug).

Comment: Are you linking to the Visual Studio 2013 libraries. These should be in the vc12 folder. Yes vc12 = Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I had previously linked it to the vc10 libs, but when I changed it the error was still the same... in the the application, the command line had the same error and gave me a new one: "OpenCV Error: Assertion failed <0 <=i && i < <int>vv.size<>> in cv::_InputArray::getMat, file ...\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 977"

Comment: Update: Instead of breaking it, I decided to press continue and it gives me this: "Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: vector subscript out of range" Is something in my code wrong?

Comment: Please share your input image, it will help to locate the errors.

Comment: You should build OpenCV with VS2013, that way you can ensure your code and OpenCV DLLs are using the same version of CRT libs.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known compatibility issue between vs2013 and opencv

Try to replace

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
```

with

```
vector<cv::Mat> coutours;
```

That works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code.

[image]
[image]

This example (probably) doesn't make sense, but your code works.

This entire thing about VC10, VC12, ... can be quite messy. My suggestion is to try to follow the [OpenCV HOWTO for Windows and Visual Studio](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html). Maybe that way you will get around the problems you described in your question (or even find out what's wrong).